# Android contacts use ContactsSource for lower api levels and ContactsAccountType as default in contacts.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, contacts, android-contacts

I have been experiencing a small problem with the contacts application for android 2.1 where my app causes the contacts application to crush when displaying contacts due to the contacts xml definition.

```
<ContactsAccountType
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    viewContactNotifyService=".ContactViewedService">
   ...
</ContactsAccountType>
```

The error that was being displayed was :

```
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top level element must be ContactsSource
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.contacts.model.ExternalSource.inflate(ExternalSource.java:133)
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.contacts.model.ExternalSource.inflate(ExternalSource.java:104)
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.contacts.model.ContactsSource.ensureInflated(ContactsSource.java:98)
05-01 12:43:31.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.contacts.model.Sources.getInflatedSource(Sources.java:311)
```

I managed to trace and found that I needed to switch ContactsAccountType to ContactsSource in the contacts.xml file which is deprecated so my question is:

Is there a way I can have contactsSource for lower api versions as a fallback and ContactsAccountType as the default in my xml description?

Comment: I am having gingerbread in my phone, and even I see the same error. The LogViewer tells "top level element must be contactssource" error when ever I try to add new contact and it crashes then. No clue how to fix without returning to factory default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

You can define old xml with **ContactsSource**      in default **xml** folder

And create second xml with **ContactsAccountType** in **xml-v11** folder.

[image]

Comment: Wow I didn't know the api levels can be namespaced that way. Thanks